# .net http handler redirect to rtmp and flex

Tags: asp.net, .net, apache-flex, httphandler, rtmp

I have an `http handler` (`.ashx`) that I use to display an image or swf or flv based on the id. So, for instance http://www.example.com/myHandler.ashx?id=1234 it displays the image for id 1234. I am using this as a source for an image tag or swf loader or video display in flex. In my handler if the item is a video I just redirect the request to the http address of the progressive download video(`flv`). That works great. But if **I want to redirect the request to a streaming server using the rtmp protocol**, it doesn't do a thing. Any thoughts? Is it even possible to redirect to anything other than a http address?

I also have `weborb` for dot net available which apparently has rtmp tunneling available. Is it possible to set up the request in that way?

Comment: Have you tried `URL Rewrite` instead of simple `Redirect`? Like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837682/programmatically-producing-rewritten-urls

Answer (score 1):

http://www.example.com/myHandler.ashx?id=1234

Use the Querysting to get the id and use the get stored procedure to retrive the image and return..later assing that return path in the image src