# Programmatically Producing rewritten URLs?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

Using IIS Rewrite over a ASP.NET 4.0 application. Is there some function I could call from within ASP.NET that would transform a string URL to the rewritten URL? I would like to be able to do this in code-behind.

Something like this: `string ProduceRewrittenUrl(string publicUrl)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes this the `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(string)`

reference: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx

a global place to call it is the `protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)` on `global.asax`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in code, take a look at using the `Application_BeginRequest()` event of *Global.asax*.